# Hive to GCP BigQuery Sync

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

We need to move data from Hive tables (Hadoop) to GCP (Google Cloud Platform) BigQuery at regular intervals (hourly/daily/any). There are multiple tables and the volume of data is huge. Can you please let me know if Cloud Data Flow (CDF) can be used in this situation? Any alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: Where is your Hadoop cluster(s) installed and running i.e. on-premise or on GCP? Depending on your situation, we can help you build your strategy.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Hadoop cluster is not on GCP. It cluster is on-premise.

Comment: There are umpteen number of solutions depending on the timescales you have but any or all of them will involve using GSUTIL to copy data from HDFS (to local file system) and then to GCS. Alternatively, you may also develop a solution using MySQL basckup and restoring them back on GCP.

Comment: Thanks Raunak! Can we use Google Cloud data flow to get table from hive and store it in Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: No. This cannot be done until unless the HDFS namespace is extended and visible on to GCP. The best approach here is to copy HDFS data across environments.

Comment: Hi, can you please mark the last comment as an answer?

Comment: I have marked as complete! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are umpteen number of solutions depending on the timescales you have but any or all of them will involve using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to copy data from HDFS (to the local file system) and then to GCS. Alternatively, you may also develop a solution using MySQL backup and restoring them back on GCP